# Supervisor on Debian Wheezy: another program is already listening on a port that one of our HTTP servers is configured to use

Tags: debian, supervisord

When I run `service supervisor start` I run into the following error:

```
Starting supervisor: Error: Another program is already listening on a port that one of our HTTP servers is configured to use.  Shut this program down first before starting supervisord.
For help, use /usr/bin/supervisord -h
```

Content of **/var/log/superuser/supervisord.log**:

```
2014-08-04 16:25:45,891 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2014-08-04 16:25:45,891 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/com.domain.subdomain.conf" during parsing
```

**Good-to-know-stuff:**
- I use Debian Wheezy on a Digital Ocean server.
- I have tried to check the ports supervisor uses in a clean Vagrant box with the same specs, but I have got the same errors.

How could I check which port is the source of this error?

Comment: You can use netstat to find out which process is listening to which port

Comment: @Hemang I know that, but I do not know which port is the interesting one in this situation. How could I find out that?

Comment: I am not sure about configuration of the supervisor and what ports it uses. However, if you can get it running on different box, you can still use netstat to find out what ports running supervisor uses.

Comment: @Hemang it is on a running Server, so I cannot make unsure things. But as soon as I can, I will install it on a Vagrant box. Thanks

Comment: @Hemang I ran the [following](http://basebox.libera.cc/debian-wheezy-64.box) 64bit Debian 7.2 (Wheezy) package in Vagrant, but I have got the same error with the 'clean' install too. So sad...

Comment: this symptom happens when supervisord is used both on host outside any container as well as inside a ubuntu docker container on same host ... both do get their own file   ...   /var/run/supervisor.sock  ...  however when issuing the stop and start from inside container I see the same error message shown on title of this question

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I solved my problem by unlinking the `.sock` file.

```
sudo unlink /var/run/supervisor.sock
```

If this does not help you should check and unlink the file at `/tmp/supervisor.sock`.

Comment: what is the .sock file for?

Comment: @Ben the .sock file a special file that is a unix domain socket that is used for inter process networking - you can see more here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket

Comment: In my case it was under
unlink /var/run/supervisor/supervisor.sock

Comment: Not a good idea, if supervisord still running, you lose the pid and your supervisord keeps running forever. This answer is the best: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40289401/775935

Comment: You may use find command to search for exact location `sudo find / -name supervisor.sock`

Answer (score 63):

Type this in your terminal

```
ps -ef | grep supervisord
```

You will get some pid of supervisord just like these

```
root   2503  1  0 Nov19 ?  00:03:23 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/supervisord
root   21337 2556  0 18:15 pts/8   00:00:00 grep --color=auto supervisord
```

And the PID is 2503

Then type this:

```
kill -s SIGTERM 2503
```

It should work

Comment: When I had the issue, it didn't unlink the sock file and that was the problem. I think it was something like a permission issue but I don't remember already.

Answer (score 14):

Similar to @N'falyKaba's answer but perhaps a bit more direct, as of newer versions of Supervisor you can use `supervisorctl pid` to get the pid, kill it, and restart:

```
$ kill -s SIGTERM $(supervisorctl pid)
```

To restart:

```
$ supervisord -c /path/to/supervisord.conf
```

Source: [docs](http://supervisord.org/running.html#supervisorctl-actions).

Comment: This is the best option. You won't lose the PID and your supervisord won't keep running forever.

Answer (score 9):

My situation was a little specific, but this may still be helpful.

I was running a couple docker containers on the same host.  All containers were running in [host networking mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/#default-networks). Each container had several processes monitored by supervisor.

The first container would always come up, and all the others would fail with the warning that the OP mentioned: `Another program is already listening on a port that one of our HTTP servers is configured to use.  Shut this program down first before starting supervisord.`

For me, the issue was that I had the following line in my supervisor config:

```
[inet_http_server]
port=127.0.0.1:9001

[supervisorctl]
```

The first container would successfully bind to port 9001, and each subsequent container would fail to start because they would also try to bind to that same port, which was already taken.

I replaced these lines with the following, switching from a http server binding on localhost:9001 to a server running on a unix domain socket.

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock
```

That fixed the port collisions and all the containers were able to start.

Comment: Bit different issue as you're using it on a "higher level context" and yours is more like an issue you had when working with Docker. But yeah, I think more and more people start using Docker (just like I use it in most cases), so it will be helpful for some I'm sure. Thanks :)

Comment: Had this exact problem, seems so obvious now!

Answer (score 8):

Had the same problem here. Solution was that `systemctl stop supervisor.service` did not stop the service. **supervisord might be still running** although you think otherwise.

Be sure you tried that before manually unlinking the socket.

I often encountered problems doing `/etc/init.d/supervisor restart` although `/etc/init.d/supervisor stop && /etc/init.d/supervisor start` works.